# Can we break the coded message?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography, language

One guy communicate with his Girl friend via a secret coded message:

**"Sarà, If you're listening, I know I can't ask you for another chance, I only hope by you have found your safe haven, I took advantage of you, of your commitment to help others and out you in a place that's every Doctor's
nightmare. I have considered many ways to apologize, but I must arrive at one. I wish i could do this differently, but it's too late for that now, it's too late for you and for others"**

Did you recognize anything here? anything that he may trying to tell her?

> Hint: Message has enough information and it helps her to meet him directly.

I am not sure which Tag is suitable for this, if any one has help me.

Comment: [tag:cryptic-clues] is almost certainly wrong here.  Perhaps you mean [tag:steganography]?

Comment: @CR241 is **differently** correct?  Is the apparently missing word "I only hope by ***now*** you have found..." correct?

Comment: @Rubio You almost tried to reach, but it's not correct. Keep trying 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is -

> He wanted to meet Sarà at the hospital(Doctors Nightmare) at One o clock(Time).

How

> This is picked up from **[Prison Break Season 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prison_Break_(season_2))**